# No sorting correctly

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program for a class. I can get the program to sort the names by time. However, when the program goes to sort by the first letter of a name I get this.

[image: Output]

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Race {
    public static void main (String[] args){
//declaring Variables
        String runner1, runner2, runner3, infoRunner1, infoRunner2, infoRunner3, inputUser, rankOutput;
        int runtime1, runtime2, runtime3;


    inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter runner one name: ");
        runner1 = (inputUser);
    inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runner one time: ");
        runtime1 = Integer.parseInt(inputUser);
           infoRunner1 = (runner1 + " " + runtime1);
    inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter runner two name: ");
        runner2 = (inputUser);
    inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Please enter runner two time ");
        runtime2 = Integer.parseInt(inputUser);
            infoRunner2 = (runner2 +" " + runtime2);
    inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter runner three name: ");
        runner3 = (inputUser);
    inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Please enter runner three time ");
        runtime3 = Integer.parseInt(inputUser);
            infoRunner3 = (runner3 +" " + runtime3);
//Naming sort
        String OutputName = "";
        if (runner1.compareToIgnoreCase(runner2) <= 0 && runner1.compareToIgnoreCase(runner3) <= 0) {
        OutputName += infoRunner1 + "\n";
        if (runner2.compareToIgnoreCase(runner3) <= 0) {
            OutputName += infoRunner3 + "\n";
            OutputName += infoRunner2 + "\n";
            } else {
                OutputName += infoRunner2 + "\n";
                OutputName += infoRunner3 + "\n";
            }
    }
    else
        if (runner2.compareToIgnoreCase(runner1) <= 0 && runner2.compareToIgnoreCase(runner3) <= 0) {
            OutputName += infoRunner2 + "\n";
            if (runner1.compareToIgnoreCase(runner3) <= 0) {
                OutputName += infoRunner1 + "\n";
                OutputName += infoRunner3 + "\n";
            } else {
                OutputName += infoRunner1 + "\n";
                OutputName += infoRunner2 + "\n";
            }
        }
    else
        if (runner3.compareToIgnoreCase(runner2) <= 0 && runner3.compareToIgnoreCase(runner1) <= 0) {
            OutputName += infoRunner3 + "\n";
            if (runner2.compareToIgnoreCase(runner1) <= 0) {
                OutputName += infoRunner2 + "\n";
                OutputName += infoRunner1 + "\n";
            } else {
                OutputName += infoRunner1 + "\n";
                OutputName += infoRunner2 + "\n";
            }
        }
//ranking
        String firstplace = "";
        String secondplace = "";
        String thirdplace = "";
        if (runtime1 >= runtime2 && runtime1 >= runtime3){
            firstplace = infoRunner1;}
        else if (runtime1 >= runtime2 && runtime1 <= runtime3){
            secondplace = infoRunner1;}
        else if (runtime1 <= runtime2 && runtime1 <= runtime3){
            thirdplace = infoRunner1;}
        if (runtime2 >= runtime1 && runtime2 >= runtime3){
            firstplace = infoRunner2;}
        else if (runtime2 >= runtime1 && runtime2 <= runtime3){
            secondplace = infoRunner2;}
        else if (runtime2 <= runtime3 && runtime2 <= runtime1){
            thirdplace = infoRunner2;}
        if (runtime3 >= runtime1 && runtime3 >= runtime2){
            firstplace = infoRunner3;}
        else if (runtime3 >= runtime1 && runtime3 <= runtime2){
            secondplace = infoRunner3;}
        else if (runtime3 <= runtime1 && runtime3 <= runtime2){
            thirdplace = infoRunner3;}

    rankOutput  = thirdplace + "\n" + secondplace + "\n" +firstplace + "\n";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ranking Order\n" + rankOutput + "\nName Order \n" + OutputName);
    System.exit(0);
```

The assignment only called for certain names to be used. When I was testing the program I found it could not have the same first letter of a name. We have not gotten to the array's not sure we can use those for this assignment.

Comment: YIKES that's a lot of code for a relatively simple task like sorting. It would be much easier, more convenient and less code if you used an array of 3 strings to store the inputs. Then, you could do a simple sorting algorithm on your array to sort by date or name. I'm sure you'll get the solution to the code you've shown in a few minutes, but I suggest switching to an array format to save yourself a lot of effort in the future.

Comment: Also, the answer to your question is that in the first condition of sorting by names (where runner1 is the smallest), you accidentally put the output for when runner3 is smaller than runner2, in the condition where runner2 is smaller than runner3. If it sounds confusing, try thinking about the logical progression of the code inside the first condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this pair of lines is incorrect:

```
     if (runner2.compareToIgnoreCase(runner3) <= 0) {
        OutputName += infoRunner3 + "\n";
```

This code says that if runner2 comes before runner3, put out runner3 first, which seems wrong.  Put out runner2 then runner 3.

To find bugs like this, walk through your code by hand.  There may be other bugs, and where there is one kind of bug, look in code for similar code because the same kind of mistake may have been made more than once.

And @Robo Mop is right, there are much simpler ways.  For one thing, you can lower-case all the names first before doing any comparisons.  You can make a simple array of strings and then sort that.  Research "collections" in Java, and the sort methods.  You probably don't have to write an iterator or comparator.  Taking this approach will also allow you to extend the code to sort 10,000 runners if there is a city-wide marathon for example.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. When I get further along in the class I will look more into the things everyone has mentioned.